# How do you install pycoral on a raspberry pi?

Tags: google-coral

```
williamcochran@raspberrypi:~/coral/pycoral $ sudo apt-get install python3-pycoral
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pycoral : Depends: python3-tflite-runtime (= 2.5.0.post1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
williamcochran@raspberrypi:~/coral/pycoral $
```

Seems like pip would be a better way to do this.

i tried typing what the website said.  and it didn't work.